# what will be the scope of scope variable in link function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
var $directive = angular.module('myApp', []);
$directive.directive('myDirective', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<h4>{{title}}</h4>'
      compile: function(element, attrs){
        console.log('this is compile'); 
        return function link(scope, element, attrs){ 
           element.on('click', function(){
              scope.title = 'My Directive 2 on click'; 
              scope.dataPoint(scope.title);
           }); 
        }; 
      },
     controller: function($scope){
        $scope.title = "My Directive";
         $scope.dataPoint = function(title){
             $scope.title = title;
         };
     }
  };
});
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

In the above snippet I am trying to change the scope variable title which i declared in controller on click of the element but its not showing any changes..?

Can you guys help me out with it? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the title inside of `scope.$apply`. `scope.$apply()` will make click handler to cause Angular to enter a `digest` cycle

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.title = 'My Directive 2 on click'; 
        });
    });
}
```